# Eclipse dark theme bug after uninstalling

Tags: eclipse, plugins, themes, uninstallation, eclipse-marketplace

I installed the dark theme for Eclipse but since I didn't like it, I uninstalled it. But what happened was this.[The background of the text editor remains black after uninstalling the theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul9XQ.png)

The background of the text editor remains black after uninstalling the theme although the text color is the original from the standard white background again

(If I switch the workspace the background becomes normal, thus, I guess, it does have something to do with the .plugins folder inside the .metadata folder of the workspace)

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you mean by installing a theme? You can easily change the theme through the Eclipse preferences by: Preferences > General > Appearance. Inside the Appearance menu should be a place where you can change the theme.